# What does "$-w = true" do?

Tags: ruby, rack

I've been reading Rack's source code, and in [server.rb](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/server.rb#L259) I found:

```
$-w = true
```

It's assigning a value to a global variable. The documentation says:

```
Options may include:
    # * :warn
    #     turn on warnings ($-w = true)
```

But still it is a bit confusing for me how that  global variable works as it does not adhere to the language syntax I understand.

Also tried these:

```
$-w = "hello"
#=> "hello"

$-a = "hello"
#=> NameError: $-a is a read-only variable

$-b = "hello"
#=> "hello"

$-ww = "hello"
#=> SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
$-ww = "hello"
    ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-w` is a Ruby global variable.

This is from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html):

> `$-0` The alias to $/.
>
> `$-a` True if option -a is set. Read-only variable.
>
> `$-d` The alias of $DEBUG. See $DEBUG above for further discusison.
>
> `$-F` The alias to $;.
>
> `$-i` In in-place-edit mode, this variable holds the extension,
>   otherwise nil.
>
> `$-I` The alias to $:.
>
> `$-l` True if option -l is set. Read-only variable.
>
> `$-p` True if option -p is set. Read-only variable.
>
> `$-v` An alias of $VERBOSE. See $VERBOSE above for further discussion.
>
> `$-w` An alias of $VERBOSE. See $VERBOSE above for further discussion.